# to create and assign some COOKIE variables through javascript

Tags: javascript, session, session-variables

I want to save some info in session/cookie through Javascript.

I am trying to pull some content from mainpage and assign it to session/cookie variables
and then use it inside my iframe

I think this is the best way to get values from mainpage to an iframe

pleas let me know if this idea is a better one and guide me how to assign values to the session/cookie variables through javascript

eg:

```
URL ="sitename.com/mypage/1.php?test=1&mode=0"  //just an example url

to session variable 'ifra_url' = "sitename.com/mypage/1.php?test=1&mode=0"
```

**I go thorught some websites which says its not possible to create session with javascript as session is server side scripted and I update my question how to create COOKIE with javascript as it saves data in browser not anywhere else**

Comment: u can use sime div rather iframe for this...after building the URL, get the content using Ajax and set div.innerHTML to this..you may need to remove meta,html tags which is not that difficult..

Comment: I am using iframe to show a popup form,... its a different context I am dealing with I think, I want to pull some content into this iframe from the main page(parent page which generates iframe)

Comment: that's correct, you can't create a session but you can [create a cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I think I got my answer

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

more reference http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html